# RandomForest with VST data

Tags: r, classification, random-forest, data-transformation, bagging

I used the randomForest() function in R for bagging without a training data set to identify the important features characterizing the members of groups A and B (binary testing). I get the following output from a scaled dataset:

```
Type of random forest: classification
Number of trees: 80
No. of variables tried at each split: 11
OOB estimate of error rate: 14.94%
Confusion matrix:
       A     B     class.error
A     35     6     0.14
B      7    39     0.15
```

If I repeat the random forest analysis with the exact same data frame but variance-stabilised transformed (VST) data, I get:

```
Type of random forest: classification
Number of trees: 80
No. of variables tried at each split: 11
OOB estimate of error rate: 0%
Confusion matrix:
       A     B     class.error
A     41     0     0
B      0    46     0
```

I know that in either case, bagging is resulting in very optimistic outcomes.

However, why is the VST run so different from the version above where I did also not have highly skewed data?
Also, if I look directly into the votes of the VST random forest run and set all the values set to one as "yes", I get a predicted probability of 0.85. How can this be explained in consideration of an OOB estimate of error rate of 0 %? I mean 0.97 is quite close to 1. What would be a better cut-off value?

```
> rf$votes
    A          B         Group Yes_NO
01  1.0000000 0.00000000  A  Yes
02  1.0000000 0.00000000  A  Yes
03  1.0000000 0.00000000  A  Yes
04  1.0000000 0.00000000  A  Yes
05  0.9677419 0.03225806  A   No
06  0.9600000 0.04000000  A   No
07  1.0000000 0.00000000  A  Yes
08  0.9310345 0.06896552  A   No
09  1.0000000 0.00000000  A  Yes
10  1.0000000 0.00000000  A  Yes
...

> table(rf$votes$Yes_NO)
No Yes 
  6  35 

> 35/41
[1] 0.8536585
```

Comment: Using only 80 trees suggests that these results are strongly reflective of the high variance of the RF procedure, rather than any particularly remarkable feature of your data. Additionally, the small number of observations places sharp limits on the kinds of inferences we can draw.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. The authors of this article: 10.1007/978-3-642-31537-4_13 suggest the usage of 64 to 128 trees. From your experience, which number would you recommend instead? I completely agree that the small number of observations is critically limiting, but why do I observe this drop in error after the variance-stabilizing transformation?

Comment: If these results are dominated by random variation, then it's not necessarily true that they are truly different; merely exhibiting high variance. A small number of realizations from a random process will have higher variance than a larger number of realizations. // Random forest's splits depend on the ordering of the data, so they should be insensitive to monotonic injective transformations. Is the VST you used monotonic injective?

Comment: Yes, the VST I approached undergoes strictly monotonic and hence injective mapping but this should then not explain the difference? I have now repeated the bootstrapping aggregations with more than 200 seeds set and the mean OOB estimate of error rate remains very low in both cases, for the second one, mean = 0.01, standard error = 0.0002. Would it be advisable to add a few columns with random numbers to the data frame and see if they are used with high importance during the classification? In this case, the error rate will probably increase but it may give an indicator of random assignments?

Comment: Yes, I agree; in this case, the transformation is probably not the reason for the difference. That's why I think that variance is the most likely explanation -- your result from 1 trial with a small number of trees on a small data set is not a precise comparison. // It would be interesting to see what your model does with random data; indeed, this is the key step used in the [tag:boruta] feature selection strategy, and seems similar to your proposal here in its core concept.

Comment: Wow, that is a very nice algorithm. Thank you for pointing it out. When I evalute the features of the randomForest() outcome with the boruta feature extraction, I get a total Mean Decrease Accuracy between 30-40 and Mean Decrease Gini of 25-30 for confirmed attributes. The total Mean Decrease Accuracy for random assignments is between 10-15 (Mean Decrease Gini: 2-10). So, there seems to be a lot of random variation but is it fair to say that nonetheless, the signal is higher than the noise?

Comment: Boruta selects features which are statistically more informative than features whose values a permuted, i.e. random values with the same marginal distribution. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i mean!